# How to apply element-wise operations without using for loops and without influencing the speed

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, filter, bsxfun

Suppose that I have an RGB image matrix and I want to apply some spatial filters on it. 
In general I want to apply element-wise operations (note that it's a college assignment and I'm not permitted to use any built-in functions available in the Image Processing toolbox). I decided to write the filters as functions and then apply `bsxfun` to these functions on the image.

A simple example would be this:
I want to add 50 to all gray levels of an image and then replace all gray levels with above 200 with 200. Here's my code:

```
a='C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\IP_abadpour\S45C-113050518040.jpg';  
b=imread(a);  
b(:,:,1)=b(:,:,1)+50;  
b(:,:,2)=b(:,:,2)+50;  
b(:,:,3)=b(:,:,3)+50;  
c=reshape(b,[],1);  
d=bsxfun(@test,c,200);
```

`test` is a function in this form:

```
function Out = test(in,a)  
   if in>a
      in=200;
   end
   Out = in;
end
```

This code won't work because in the second line "in > a" is a matrix having 0's and 1's (I mean all of the elements are not 1 and should not be) so the debugger won't branch into the `if` statement.

Could you guide me how to write this function and how to apply spatial and fourier analyses on the image, without affecting the performance and run-time speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of suggestions:

1. First of all, you don't need to add 50 to each layer of the RGB matrix individually. You can just do:

   ```
   b = b + 50;
   ```
2. Why do you reshape `b` before passing it to `bsxfun`? The size of the output of `bsxfun` is the same as your image's, there's really no need in reshaping here anything.
3. Regarding your `test` function, note what the [official documentation of `bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) states:

   > A binary element-wise function of the form `C = fun(A,B)` accepts arrays `A` and `B` of arbitrary but equal size and returns output of the same size. Each element in the output array `C` is the result of an operation on the corresponding elements of `A` and `B` only. `fun` must also support scalar expansion, such that if `A` or `B` is a scalar, `C` is the result of applying the scalar to every element in the other input array.

   So `bsxfun` performs singleton expansion and "inflates" its two input arrays to the same size, and then applies the specified function to the inflated arrays. The element-wise function `fun` operates, in fact, on the arrays, not scalars. I don't see any actual gain in employing `bsxfun` here.

   That said, you can simplify your code as shown in [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724)'s suggestion, or implement it as a function:

   ```
   function out = test(in, a);
       out = in;
       out(in > a) = a;
   ```

   I assume that if you were using the value 210 instead of 200, you'd like to cap all gray levels with 210 as well, so you should really be using `a` instead of a hard-coded value 200. You could also write your function like so:

   ```
   function out = test(in, a)
       out = min(in, a);
   ```

   and then invoke it with:

   ```
   d = test(b, 200);
   ```

   instead of the more complicated `d = bsxfun(@test, b, 200)`.

   Another alternative is to use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

   ```
   d = arrayfun(@(x)test(x, 200), a);
   ```

   or

   ```
   d = arrayfun(@test, a, 200 * ones(size(a)));
   ```

   in which `arrayfun` will apply `test` element-wise, and the `test` function would need to operate only on scalars. However, `arrayfun` usually runs slower than loops, let alone vectorized operations.
4. For spatial analysis, check out [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) just like [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724) suggested (or implement your own 2-D convolution, for the sake of practice). For Fourier analysis, consider using the [`fft2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html) and [`ifft2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft2.html) functions in the frequency domain.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well the function that you suggested works well except that max function should be replaced by min.But another question rose up. Why my function doesn't work. I mean if you stop the debugger in the funtion you'll see that "in"is not a scalar and is a matrix when test is invoked and you said:there's nothing wrong with your function as it is currently writte??!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So for the example you posted you can just take advantage of the fact that most operators in matlab work on matrices natively:

```
b=imread(a);
c = a + 50;
c(c > 200) = 200;
```

It's as simple as that.

For the filtering, if you are allowed, I would have a look at the `conv2` function. You can do spatial filtering this way without transforming to the frequency domain (remeber, multiplication of a filter in the frequency domain is the same as convolution in the spatial domain). So for example a basic low pass filter:

```
lpf = ones(5)./25;
c(:,:,1) = conv2(b(:,:,1), lpf);
c(:,:,2) = conv2(b(:,:,2), lpf);
c(:,:,3) = conv2(b(:,:,3), lpf);
```